# Cannot run program "cf": error=2, No such file or directory and error=2

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cloud-foundry

This question is regarding "cf" - cloudfoundry. I have installed eclipse Mars on Mac. Also have installed `cf` and run a `brew intsall protobuf`. I am executing the following in my program from eclipse :

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

This is giving me:

> Cannot run program "cf": error=2, No such file or directory and
>   error=2, No such file or directory errors.

The `cf` command works fine from the command line but I see this error while running any `cf` commands from eclipse.

Comment: Has it got anything to do with CFML though?

Comment: FYI: Removed CFML (ColdFusion Markup Language) tag as it does not appear related.